# Can table name start with integer in Redshift

Tags: database, amazon-redshift

I have a customer trying to create a table name starting with a number followed by alphabet ( example: 1234-testtable ) and the redshift is throwing

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "1234" Position:53
```

Can't we create a table name starting with number in Amazon Redshift ?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Names and Identifiers documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_names.html), you cannot start your identifier with a digit and it cannot contain a hyphen as only
*ASCII letters, digits, underscore characters (_), or dollar signs ($)* are valid characters. The complete set rules for Redshift is:

> - Contain only ASCII letters, digits, underscore characters (_), or    dollar signs ($).
> - Begin with an alphabetic character or underscore    character.
> - Subsequent characters may include letters, digits,    underscores, or dollar signs.
> - Be between 1 and 127 characters in    length, not including quotes for delimited identifiers.
> - Contain no    quotation marks and no spaces. Not be a reserved SQL key word.

Thus you could elect for a name like `testtable_1234` instead.

Comment: I think the wording is incorrect 

"According to the Names and Identifiers documentation, you cannot start your identifier with a _letter_ and it cannot contain a hyphen as only ASCII letters, digits, underscore characters (_), or dollar signs ($) are valid characters. "      

I believe you mean "you cannot start your identifier with a **digit**"

Comment: @RalphYozzo corrected!